# Use extraHosts block in Terraform for ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

So I have an ecs-task-definition, and I want to add a value to the hosts file in my container. This can be done using the extraHosts block:

`extraHosts:    A list of hostnames and IP address mappings to append to the /etc/hosts file on the container   list(string)`

see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/terraform-aws-ecs-task-definition) for more info.

I'm trying to get this extraHosts block running in the terraform-aws-ecs-task-definition module linked above. The block I have looks like this:

```
  extraHosts = [
    {
      "ipAddress": "x.x.x.x",
      "hostname": "mongo1"
    },
    {
      "ipAddress": "x.x.x.x",
      "hostname": "mongo2"
    },
  ]
```

But this syntax gets me:

```
The given value is not suitable for child module variable "extraHosts" defined
at
.terraform/modules/ecs-task-definition/terraform-aws-ecs-task-definition-2.0.1/variables.tf:66,1-22:
element 0: string required.
```

Has anyone used the extraHosts block in the past for their IaC? Can you please advise as to the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is asking for the wrong type. The module's `extraHosts` variable wants `list(string)` while you are trying to pass `list(object(...))`).

There's already an issue at https://github.com/mongodb/terraform-aws-ecs-task-definition/issues/33 but switching the type to `list(any)` or, more precisely,  `list(object([ipAddress = string, hostname = string]))` in the module should fix it.

Comment: Good spot on that Git issue. Works fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response. I have authored a change to fix the issue. The fix is available for [v2.1.1](https://github.com/mongodb/terraform-aws-ecs-task-definition/releases/tag/v2.1.1).